# How to copy current line number in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anybody know how to copy current line number in IntelliJ IDEA 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA v12 and above we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: @AyukNayr, Ctrl + G => Ctrl + C does the thing.

Answer (score 19):

You could use `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C` to copy a reference to a line or symbol.  When used within a class, it will copy to the clipboard a string of the form `<fully qualified path>:<line number>`.

I came across this feature in the [documentation for IDEA 14](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html), but if I’m interpreting the document correctly, this feature has been available since IDEA 10.5.

Comment: This feature is also accessible as "Copy Reference" in right click menu, when you have not selected any token on the current line.

Comment: The comment above should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: now, how to jump to such a reference...?

Comment: Are these Intellij shortcuts meant to torture us? :P

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently not available in IntelliJ IDEA. One can write a plug-in that will add an action to copy current line number to the clipboard, it should not be very hard.

Comment: thx, could you please point me to the documentation or some examples how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. copy : Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C
2. move : shift+shift