# How to jump to file at a specific line in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412244 I can get a file/line reference in form of `<fully qualified path>:<line number>`; how can I jump to such a location in IDEA (e.g. if a colleague sent me that)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just use *Navigate* → *File...* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>), paste it there, and the file will open at that line :)